# order records of table by id in erlang

Tags: erlang

I have this table person

```
-record(person, {id, firstname, lastname, phone}).
```

and it contains this values :

```
12  alen     dumas        97888888
15  franco   mocci      55522225
13  ali      othmani    44444449
```

**I want to order this table by id**
and it should became like this :

```
 12  alen     dumas        97888888
  13  ali      othmani    44444449
  15  franco   mocci      55522225
```

Comment: Order them in **what**? How are you storing these records?

Comment: order records by id of person ( 12 13 15 )

Answer (score 1):

To order tuples stored in `mnesia` you need to either:

- create a table with type `ordered_set` (see option `type` in: [mnesia:create_table](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#create_table-2)) and then use [mnesia:last](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#last-1) or [mnesia:dirty_last](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#dirty_last-1)

or

- read all records and sort them outside of `mnesia`,

e.g.:

```
Select = [{#person{_ = '_'}, [], ['$_']}],
Sorted = lists:sort(mnesia:dirty_select(person, Select)),
erlang:hd(lists:reverse(Sorted)).
```

That will get all records, sort them as tuples (which should be enough considering the `id` is the first element in the record, if not use [lists:sort/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#sort-2) and specify the sorting function), then reverse the list and return the first element (in Erlang it's quicker to reverse and get the first element than return the last element of a list).